# Delphi index information with metaInfoQuery

Tags: sql, delphi, metadata

I have an error "A meta data argument [table name] value must be specified." coming out when I try to get information about indexes for columns in specified sql table with this code :

```
metaInfoQuery.ObjectName := 'my_table';
metaInfoQuery.MetaInfoKind := mkIndexFields;
metaInfoQuery.Open;
```

But this is working just fine :

```
metaInfoQuery.ObjectName := 'my_table';
metaInfoQuery.MetaInfoKind := mkIndexes;
metaInfoQuery.Open;
```

-> returns information about index names and other useful index information, but not about for which columns they apply.

So how should I transform my code with 'mkIndexes' so that it can work for 'mkIndexFields' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ObjectName to the name of the Index rather than the name of a table.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. - I also had to set BaseObjectName to the name of the table and it worked :) 
metaInfoQuery.BaseObjectName := 'my_table';    metaInfoQuery.ObjectName := 'myIndex';
metaInfoQuery.MetaInfoKind := mkIndexFields;
metaInfoQuery.Open;